# Sand like residue inside my engine bay area. Could it have been flooded........?

Tags: engine, sparkplugs, water

I just bought a car from a dealership (2013 Accord 2.4L) and I noticed today that there was sand residue near and around the engine. I was changing spark plugs today and also noticed dry powerdy sand when I lifted the engine cover. Should I be worried that It was a flood car? There were no other signs of a flood damage and the title was clean with one previous owner. Could it just be dirt?

This is the spark plug covers:

[image]

[image: This below the engine]

Comment: Take it back and Demand a full refund, it is a FLOOD vehicle, don't take No for an answer! This is against the law to sell flood vehicles without telling you they are, sue them if needed.

Comment: Really? I didn't see any other signs of flooding. What else should I look for before actually going to the dealership?

Comment: Also makes me think. If they were trying to pass it off as non-flooded vehicle, these areas are easy to spot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, maybe not. This could just be dust accumulation that has not been (steam) cleaned off properly. A general clean only does the easiest bits, a detail cleaning goes much further.

Comment: What about the dry dirt near the spark plug covers?

Comment: What about the dry dirt?

Comment: Do you think that could've been due to a flood? I did change the spark plugs and one of them had caramel looking fluid. Fuel? Not sure

Comment: Re-read my answer

Comment: I checked under the carpets, under the dashboard, glove box, under the hood, air filter, trunk, moisture residues, etc...I found nothing so far.  Where else do you think I should look? Sorry for asking so many questions. I spent a lot on this and will definitely sue this dealership if it was.

Comment: When I did my apprenticeship, we had to recover a car for someone who had managed to find a parking place in London - on a slipway for the river Thames - it's tidal so guess what happened.... Took us 2 weeks to strip & clean & dry & replace to restore the vehicle. If you did not find any evidence in the areas you looked at then there is none to find. So, if you want to sue the dealership to get your money back you need to find a different excuse. Only my opinion but your choice.